# Replacing / removing specific part of file names using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to C# and need to loop through a directory and remove the last part of any and all files that end in `_xxxxxx.xml` (an underscore followed by 6 digits).

For example, the filename `filename_A_123_456789.xml` becomes `filename_A_123.xml`.

What I have so far:

```
private static void RenameFiles(string outputPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(outputPath);
    FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
    {
        string newName = Regex.Replace(f.FullName, "(\\[_\d]\\s)", temp);

        File.Move(f.FullName, newName);
    }
}
```

But that's not working. Ang CSharp Regexxers out there?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? How is it not working? Did it rename the files to something else? Did it throw an exception?

Comment: `string newName = Regex.Replace(f.FullName, @"_\d{6}(?=\.[^.]*$)", "");`? Or, `_\d{6}(?=\.xml$)` if there is always an xml extension.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yours has been the closest, but it's only renaming the first file in the loop

Comment: What do you mean? The regex does its job, doesn't it? The rest is your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
_\d{6}(\.[^.]+)$
```

and replace with `$1` instead.

The regex is matching 6 digits, then group 1 (`(\.[^.]+)`) matches the extension, which you replace with in the replacement string. The extension is matched by "a dot followed by a bunch of non-dots". Also note that the end of string anchor `$` to assert that all of this must be at the end of the string.

Change your code to:

```
string newName = Regex.Replace(f.FullName, @"_\d{6}(\.[^.]+)$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex is fine for your need. As an alternative, here is a regex free solution if you want to use one:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var source = @"filename_A_123_456789.xml";
    var slices =  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source).Split('_');
    var last = slices.Last();
    var isSpecific = last.Length == 6 && last.All(char.IsDigit);
    var result = string.Join("_", isSpecific ? slices.Take(slices.Length - 1) : slices) + Path.GetExtension(source);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

- We split the name by '_'
- We take the last section
- We define if the last section is a specific part
- We concat back everthing minus the last one if it is a specific part

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VZw0vs)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't quantify the `\d` in any way to define that you are looking for 6 digits to be exact.

Use this instead:

`(\S*)_\d{6}(\.xml) /m`

This regex captures all non-whitespace characters before the `_` followed by six digits, and the extension `.xml` into two separate capturing groups.

Then replace with `$1$2`, group 1 followed by group 2.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1qeThz/5)

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
string newName = Regex.Replace(f.FullName, "(\\_\\d{6}\\.xml)", ".xml");
```